# Deploy with Capistrano: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, git, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to make a deploy at my web site and it normally connects on my server, but the console shows the error: C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capistrano-2.9.0/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:106in ``´: No such file or directory - git ls-remote callis@callis.d2b.com.br:repo/site.git HEAD

There's a print: 
[image: Capistrano Error]

I've spent much time searching for solutions, many people had this same issue and they just used cap deploy on MINGW32 but it doesnt work to me.

Ps: It's the first time i'm making a deploy with capistrano, so i would ask for please, to consider every little thing that i could forget, etc.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1. check if `git` is installed on your **remote** server
2. check if path to `git` is in `PATH` environment variable

Comment: I've checked and git is normally installed on my remote server, but how can i set the path to git?